# How to display composed quadtrees using C language?

Tags: c, algorithm, printing, tree, quadtree

Currently I’m trying to implement different functions to realize operations on quadtrees using C language.

Context:

A quadtree (black and white picture) is:

- White
- Black
- Is broken down into 4 sub-images: top-left,top-right,bottom-left,bottom-right

Pictures are represented by the next struct:

```
typedef struct block_image
{
    int allBlack; //boolean
    struct block_image * son[4];
}block_image;
typedef block_image *image;
```

If pointer == NULL, then picture is white

If the pointer is pointing toward a struct where allBlack == true, the picture is black and son[0], son['1'], son[2] and son[3] are NULL.

If the pointer is pointing toward a struct where allBlack == false, the picture is gotten by a decomposition in 4 picture and son[0], son['1'], son[2] and son[3] are in top-left, top-right, bottom-left and bottom-right.

With this information, it is possible to implement three functions to create an image:

Build_white(): to build a white picture:

```
image Build_white()
{
    image newImage = NULL;
    return newImage;
}
```

Build_black(): to build a black picture:

```
image Build_black()
{
    image newImage = malloc(sizeof(block_image));
    newImage->allBlack = 1;
    newImage->son[0] = NULL;
    newImage->son[1] = NULL;
    newImage->son[2] = NULL;
    newImage->son[3] = NULL;
    return newImage;
}
```

Build_composed(image topL, image topR, image bottomL, image bottomR): to build a composed picture:

```
image Build_composed(image topL, image topR, image bottomL, image bottomR)
{
    image newImage = malloc(sizeof(block_image));
    newImage->allBlack = 0;
    newImage->son[0] = topL;
    newImage->son[1] = topR;
    newImage->son[2] = bottomL;
    newImage->son[3] = bottomR;
    return newImage;
}
```

Problem:

But after that, it is necessary to implement a function can print the picture, e.g white picture is represented by “W”, black picture is represented by “B” and composed picture is represented by +img1img2img3img4, e.g +WBBW.

So, currently, I’m trying to code this function and I pass to print black or white picture (not composed).

My current function:

```
void normalDisplay(image myPicture)
{
    if(myPicture == NULL)
    {
        printf("W");
    }
    else if(myPicture->allBlack == 1 && myPicture->son[0] == NULL && myPicture->son[1] == NULL && myPicture->son[2] == NULL && myPicture->son[3] == NULL)
    {
        printf("N");
    }
}
```

in main():
Image white1 = Build_white();

Image black1 = Build_black();

If I do normalDisplay(white1); I get “W” on the terminal, and if I do normalDisplay(black1); I get “B” on the terminal.

Else, I don’t know how to print a composed function, how to manage different possibilities on my function to can print more complex picture.

For example, this picture (course example):

[image]

can be coded like this:

```
image composed = Build_composed(
            Build_black(),
            Build_white(),
            Build_white(),
            Build_composed(
                Build_black(),
                Build_white(),
                Build_composed(
                    Build_white(),
                    Build_black(),
                    Build_lack(),
                    Build_white()
                ),
                Build_black()
            )
        );
```

And should be displayed with: +BWW+BW+WBBWB using normalDisplay function.

So, anyone could help me to understand how I could display a composed image with a postfix notation by explaining how to modify my function so that it can consider a maximum of cases?

Comment: `typedef block_image *image;` do not hide pointers behind a typedef.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how I could display a composed image with a postfix notation by explaining how to modify my function so that it can consider a maximum of cases?

That's really trivial. Just display it for this cell or display for the childs.

```
typedef struct block_image image;
void normalDisplay(image *t) {
    if (t == NULL) {
       printf("W"); 
    } else if (t->allBlack) {
       printf("B");
    } else {
       printf("+");
       normalDisplay(t->son[0]);  // upper left
       normalDisplay(t->son[1]);  // upper right
       normalDisplay(t->son[2]);  // lower left
       normalDisplay(t->son[3]);  // lower right
   }
}
```