# How to free all memory blocks of a picture using quadree structure with different cases?

Tags: c, algorithm, memory, quadtree

Few weeks ago, I was trying to implement a function to display a quadtree. My current problem is concerning the same work, so I pass you this link for all the context: [How to display composed quadtrees using C language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70543148/how-to-display-composed-quadtrees-using-c-language/70544929#70544929)
(I'm using a few features that come from this post)

the quadtree structure:

```
typedef struct block_image
{
    int allBlack; //boolean
    struct block_image * son[4];
}block_image;
typedef block_image *image;
```

Currently, I’m working on a function to free all memory blocks of a quadtree. For example, if a quadtree is white, there is nothing to do because the pointer to the structure is already NULL. If a quadtree is black, we free the pointer and set it to NULL. Else, if it is a composed picture, we take care of freeing the space of the different sons.

summary: returns all blocks of an image to the memory.

My current program:

```
void freeMemory(image myImage)
{
    if(myImage == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }
    else if(myImage->allBlack)
    {
        free(myImage);
        myImage = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        freeMemory(myImage->son[0]);
        freeMemory(myImage->son[1]);
        freeMemory(myImage->son[2]);
        freeMemory(myImage->son[3]);
    }  
}
```

However, I am not sure how to check my function.
For exemple, I decided to create a white quadree and a black quadtree. But when I used freeMemory fonction and normalDisplay to see the representation of the two quadrees before and after, there was no difference.

```
printf("\nfreeMemory\n\n");
image white = Build_white();
image black = Build_black();
printf("before\n");
normalDisplay(black);
printf("\n");
printf("after\n");
freeMemory(black);
normalDisplay(black);
printf("\n");
printf("before\n");
normalDisplay(white);
printf("\nafter\n");
freeMemory(white);
normalDisplay(white);   
printf("\n");
```

The result:

[image]

As you can see, there was no difference between display before and after memory.

And this is the simplest case, after that it should also work with composed images,e.g.

- N +BBNB B +N+NNB+NBNNBN.

Someone advised me to use valgrind, telling me that for my program to work, there must be as many malloc() as free(). But I don't really know how to interpret the results (and if it is really useful).

the result (My variable names was not in english so, affichageNormal == normalDisplay, Rendmemoire == freeMemory and Construit_noir == Build_black)

[image]

P.S. I also have two function isWhite and isBlack to tell if a picture is black (no white elements) or white (no black element):

```
int isWhite(image myImage)
{
    if(myImage == NULL)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if(myImage->allBlack)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else if(isWhite(myImage->son[0]) && isWhite(myImage->son[1]) && isWhite(myImage->son[2]) && isWhite(myImage->son[3]))
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}


int isblack(image myImage)
{
    if(myImage == NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else if(myImage->allBlack)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if(isBlack(myImage->son[0]) && isBlack(myImage->son[1]) && isBlack(myImage->son[2]) && isBlack(myImage->son[3]))
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It may be useful for the function.

Edit:
In case of doubt I also add the code of normalDisplay :

```
void normalDisplay(image myImage)
{
    if(myImage == NULL)
    {
        printf("B");
    }
    else if(myImage->allBlack)
    {
        printf("N");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("+");
        normalDisplay(myImage->son[0]);
        normalDispay(myImage->son[1]);
        normalDisplay(myImage->son[2]);
        normalDisplay(myImage->son[3]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you call `normalDisplay(black)` after `freeMemory(black)`? Once you have passed a pointer to `free` you should never attempt to dereference that pointer again. Any attempt to dereference an invalid pointer (which it will be after `free`) will lead to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Also remember that arguments to functions are passed *by value*. Which means that the value used in the call will be copied into the argument variable, and any modifications of the argument variable will be to that variable and only that variable. The original value used in the call will not be affected. So an assignment like `myImage = NULL` will not affect the variable used in the actual `freeMemory` call.

Comment: The valgrind issue is a big deal. Can you show us the `affuchageNormal` function and the code calling it?

Comment: @Jeffrey affichageNormal is the same function that normalDisplay, I just translated the names of my variables to simplify understanding

Comment: Please note that `typedef block_image *image;` is not a good idea, as usually is to hide a pointer with a `typedef`. As already noted, you may need to change the function signature to `void freeMemory(block_image **myImage)` or return (and use) the modified pointer.

Comment: @Bob__ It's not necessarily a good idea, but that's how the assignment was conceived and to change it would force me to rethink everything. (The teacher has written the structure as it should be used, unfortunately)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A robust way to free the memory from the quadtree is to make sure you feedback that a pointer no longer is pointing to valid memory. Since your current `freeMemory` only takes an `block_image` pointer, the function cannot convey this information back to the caller.

Better would be to change its interface to provide this facitily with another level of indirection.

```c
void freeMemory(image *myImage) {
    if (myImage != NULL && *myImage != NULL) {
        int sonSize = sizeof((*myImage)->son) / sizeof((*myImage)->son[0]);
        while (sonSize) freeMemory(&(*myImage)->son[--sonSize]);
        free(*myImage);
        *myImage = NULL;
    }
}
```

*On a side note, your original `freeMemory` does have a memory leak, but hoping you can figure that out.*

This way, `*myImage = NULL` will convey this change to the caller. On the calling side it would look something like this:

```c
puts("\nfreeMemory\n");
image white = Build_white();
image black = Build_black();
puts("before");
normalDisplay(black);
puts("");
puts("after");
freeMemory(&black);
normalDisplay(black);
puts("");
puts("before");
normalDisplay(white);
puts("\nafter");
freeMemory(&white);
normalDisplay(white);
puts("");
```

With this your `normalDisplay` will better provide you with an "image" of the situation.